# I want to call a Kivy popup window in specific condition in python file

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I have a function that will display a main popup, and when the user close the popup by tapping any where another popup will appear depending on the passed value as a parameter for the function, the problem is the style of popup content, when I use **.kv** file is looks perfect but, when I try to create the same style using **.py** file there is so many problems appear to me, so there is any way to call the popup window from **.kv** file and use it in **.py** file ?

My function in **.py** file:

```
def show_popup(result):
    def show_second_popup(self, *args):
        if result == True:
            # Show popup 1 

        elif result == False:
            # Show popup 2
        

        # Show the main popup
        str = Label(markup= True, text_size=(190, 160), text= "This is the main popup" , 
                 halign="center", valign="center", color= (0,0,0,1),font_size= 24)
        popupWindow = Popup( 
                        auto_dismiss= True,
                        content= str, 
                        size_hint= (0.8,0.4), 
                        pos_hint= {'x': 0.15,'y': 0.3}, 
                        title= "", separator_height= 0
                        )
        
        popupWindow.open()

        popupWindow.bind(on_dismiss= show_second_popup)
```

The popup style in **.kv** file:

```
<PopupTrue@Popup>
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: ""
    separator_height: 0
    size_hint: 0.8, 0.6
    background_color: (0,0,0,0)
    background_normal: ''

    


    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        padding: 0, 10, 10, 10
        border: 50
        border_color: (1,1,1,1)

        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba:(255/255,255/255,255/255,1)

            RoundedRectangle:
                pos: self.x - 20, self.y - 10
                size: self.width + 40, self.height - 60
                radius: [40]   

        Image:
            source: 'icon.png'



        Label: 
            text: "This popup appear if the condition was TRUE"
            color: 0,0,0,1
            font_size: 25
            

            
        CloseButton:
            text: "Close"
            color: 0,0,0,1
            size_hint: (None , None)
            width: 105
            height: 40
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5}
            on_release: root.dismiss() 



<PopupFalse@Popup>
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: ""
    separator_height: 0
    size_hint: 0.8, 0.6
    background_color: (0,0,0,0)
    background_normal: ''

    


    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        padding: 0, 10, 10, 10
        border: 50
        border_color: (1,1,1,1)

        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba:(255/255,255/255,255/255,1)

            RoundedRectangle:
                pos: self.x - 20, self.y - 10
                size: self.width + 40, self.height - 60
                radius: [40]   

        Image:
            source: 'icon.png'



        Label: 
            text: "This popup appear if the condition was False"
            color: 0,0,0,1
            font_size: 25
            

            
        CloseButton:
            text: "Close"
            color: 0,0,0,1
            size_hint: (None , None)
            width: 105
            height: 40
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5}
            on_release: root.dismiss()
```

I want the main popup appear from python file, and call another popup from .kv file, because my .kv file popup has canvas for the button and popup layout, and I faced a problem with writing the canvas part.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I find the answer, I tried to create a two classes with a Popup parameter, and I named the classes as the name in the .kv file, finally I just call the class with open() function. :)

```
class PopupTrue(Popup):
      pass 
            
class PopupFalse(Popup):
      pass 
        
def show_popup(result):
     def show_second_popup(self, *args):
          if result == True:
              # Show popup 1 
              PopupTrue().open()
        
          elif result == False:
              # Show popup 2
              PopupFalse().open()
    



     

  # Show the main popup
    str = Label(markup= True, text_size=(190, 160), text= "This is the main popup" , 
                 halign="center", valign="center", color= (0,0,0,1),font_size= 24)
    popupWindow = Popup( 
                    auto_dismiss= True,
                    content= str, 
                    size_hint= (0.8,0.4), 
                    pos_hint= {'x': 0.15,'y': 0.3}, 
                    title= "", separator_height= 0
                    )
    
    popupWindow.open()

    popupWindow.bind(on_dismiss= show_second_popup)
```